# Ajax request cancelled cause a iframe reload

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe

Code example:

```
SaveEntity().then(
function () {       
    //Reachable code
    top.CompletingTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
        //Unreachable code because of refresh current iframe by SaveEntity logic
        top.CompleteFunction();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Instead setTimeout may be used async Ajax request, that will be canceled.

Can i prevent unloading this script on iframe reloading or somehow else make this
code reachable?

Comment: I know what for best solution i need to rethink about 
not obvious refreshing iframe by SaveEntity, but that is not possible for now.

Comment: Sorry. Your question does not make any sense. There is not recognizable code or iframes in your example

Comment: @mplungjan

I simplified the code to focus on the problem itself.
All you need to know is that after SaveEntity, iframe and scripts can be unloaded and this interrupts the execution of the asynchronous code.